# How to union the procedure values for all values in my temporary table?

Tags: mysql

I have a followers table which contains a fk_usr_id and fk_usr_chef_id.
I want to return the chef data for the favorite chefs of a user. This data contains name, address, chef's experience... I can already get this data for one chef with the procedure I have written. So I need to loop through the user favorite chef_id's and call this for each ID.

1. I found how to make a temporary table which contains all chef_id's a user is following (because MySQL doesn't have array variables)
2. I wrote a statement which returns the chef_data of one chef
3. Apparently you cannot use a procedure inside a function and a function can only return one value. So my written procedure which returns a row for one chef cannot be used.
   So I create a temporary table with all needed columns for the chefdata. How do I insert this data for each chef? Or is it better to union all select statements?

TEMPORARY TABLE

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE
IF NOT EXISTS myFavChefsIds
  AS (SELECT fk_usr_chef_id as chef_id FROM followers WHERE fk_usr_id = 10217728406738088)
```

STATEMENT RETURNS DATA FOR ONE CHEF

```
SELECT * FROM ( SELECT * FROM users u
       INNER JOIN zipcodes z ON u.fk_zip_id = z.zip_id
       WHERE usr_id = id
       GROUP BY usr_firstname, usr_lastname) AS D
LEFT JOIN ( SELECT
              fk_usr_chef_id,
              count(DISTINCT fk_mls_id) as mls_cooked,
              count(*) as ord_finished,
              round(sum(rat_weight)/count(rat_weight),1) as avg_rating
       FROM ratings r
       RIGHT JOIN orders o ON o.fk_rat_id = r.rat_id
       LEFT JOIN meals m ON o.fk_mls_id = m.mls_id
       WHERE mls_date<now()
         AND o.fk_usr_cons_id IS NOT null
         AND fk_usr_chef_id = id) AS E
ON D.usr_id = E.fk_usr_chef_id;
```

PROCEDURE TO RETURN A TABLE WITH DATA OF THE FAVORITE CHEFS:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE getFavChefsDetailsAndExperience(IN usr_id int) RETURNS ?
BEGIN
  DECLARE n INT DEFAULT 0;
  DECLARE i INT DEFAULT 0;

  DROP TEMPORARY TABLE IF EXISTS myFavChefsIds;
  CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE IF NOT EXISTS myFavChefsIds
    AS (SELECT fk_usr_chef_id, @curRow := @curRow + 1 AS row_no
        FROM followers
               JOIN (SELECT @curRow := 0) r
        WHERE fk_usr_id = usr_id);

  DROP TEMPORARY TABLE IF EXISTS myFavChefsDetails;
  CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE IF NOT EXISTS myFavChefsDetails
    AS (SELECT *
        FROM ( SELECT * FROM users u INNER JOIN zipcodes z 
                                 ON u.fk_zip_id = z.zip_id
               GROUP BY usr_firstname, usr_lastname) AS D
               LEFT JOIN ( SELECT
                                  fk_usr_chef_id,
                                  count(DISTINCT fk_mls_id) as mls_cooked,
                                  count(*) as ord_finished,
                                  sum(rat_weight)/count(rat_weight),1) as avg_rating
                           FROM ratings r
                                  RIGHT JOIN orders o ON o.fk_rat_id = r.rat_id
                                  LEFT JOIN meals m ON o.fk_mls_id = m.mls_id
                           WHERE mls_date<now()
                             AND o.fk_usr_cons_id IS NOT null) AS E
                 ON D.usr_id = E.fk_usr_chef_id);

  IF NOT EXISTS (SELECT * FROM myFavChefsIds)

  THEN
    SET i=0;
    SELECT COUNT(*) AS n FROM myFavChefsIds;

    WHILE i<n DO
      SET i = i + 1;

      // IS IT POSSIBLE TO DO SOMETHING LIKE THIS?
      x = SELECT ... FROM ... WHERE row_no = i
      IF (i != n) THEN x += UNION

    END WHILE;

//RETURN UNION STATEMENT

  END IF;

END;
```

I want to return a table with a row for each favorite chef. This row contains all data my procedure returns for just one chef.

What to do best and how ? 
- Is it possible to insert a row of a SELECT in another table if the columns are the same?
- I can select a row for each chef. Can I UNION all these rows when I don't know beforehand how many SELECTs to UNION?

Comment: MySQL does not have a table data type, so no function can return a table.

Comment: But you can return a SELECT statement in a function. Or is that only possible if the select returns one value?

Comment: No, you cannot return a select statement, nor execute one in a stored function.